# Visual Basic 2010 - Create a class where the user can enter variables in then save it to reference in a table later

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, class

Unfortunately for me the book I brought on Visual Basic 2010 doesn't cover this and I can't find this solved anywhere else.

As part of my coursework I need to create a program and inside that program I need to have used 2 classes.

The classes are very similar so if I can do one, I can do the other. I have a form with lots of data entry boxes like when you fill in your information online. You have name, address etc, all in different boxes and you click save and you're done.

I want to take all the different variables entered and save them into a class, because I'll be saving more than one I figured I'd need a database then each time I enter a new client the client ID needs to go up one, 0001, 0002 etc. Then I want to view and be able to sort the entries in a table on a separate form.

Can anyone offer a step by step guide to do something like this.

If you could not use code and just try and explain it that would help me out a hell of a lot. I understand coding and stuff so you don't need to explain what for loops and iterations and code means.

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do:

1. Create a class that has members all the information you want to retain.
2. Whenever the user adds new information, create one such above mentioned object, populate it with the information entered and keep these objects in your program (eg an array, a list etc)
   This should take care of entering the data and maintaining them for the life span of the application.
3. But you also need to save it into the database. I would use a separate object for that, one object that will take care of saving the data in the database in order to decouple the components. In this case, the new object will have a method that will take as input parameter one of the objects mentioned at point 1 and save the information into the database. Also, you could use some edit function, that will act pretty much the same but, instead of insert, will perform edit.
   The same object will have an additional method for loading all the information from the database and populate the list - mentioned at point 2 - that you keep in your application
   You can extend this object also with delete functionality, if needed.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Your class needs to contain public properties relating to the fields you are enterring.

So you would have a Class called say `Person`.

Inside this class you would add Public Properties for each item you want to store, for instance;

- Name
- Address
- Telephone Number
- etc etc

You would then also add variables for each item you want to store, to the class `Constructor`. The constructor is the `New` Sub. This would allow you to create a new Person class, passing in the variables;

```
Dim MyNewPerson As New Person(txtName.Text, txtaddress.Text, txtTelephoneno.Text, etc, etc)
```

If you have a number of these objects, then you should use something like a List, which you can create using something like;

```
Dim MyPersonList As New List(Of Person)
```

And then you can simply add your MyNewPerson object from above, with something like;

```
MyPersonList.Add(MyNewPerson)
```

Regarding adding this to a database, this is a far bigger subject, and here I'd suggest looking at Entity Framework Code First, as this is Microsofts recommended Data Access Framework;

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/ef.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, You DONT save the variables INTO the class,
You structure your class so as to perform those functions.

So maybe your class maybe structured as...

```
Class MyClass

  Private mFileName as string
  Private mVariables as Dictionary(of TKey, TValue)


  'filename property 
  Property Filename() as string

  'variables collection as key value/pairs
  Property Variables as Dictionary(of TKey, TValue)

  'property accessor for single key/value from collection like Variables(2)
  Property VariableX(Index as integer) as string

  'function to load saved data from xml file
  Function LoadMySavedXmlData(Filename) as Dictionary(of TKey, TValue)

  'subroutine to save variables data as xml file
  Sub SaveMyXmlData(Filename as string, Data as Dictionary(of TKey, TValue))

End Class
```

And then your xml file maybe structured as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<MySavedData>
  <Filename>Bobs_Prefs.Xml</Filename>
  <Data>
    <Variable1>
      <Key>Name</Key>
      <Value>Bob Johnson</Value>
    </Variable1>
    <Variable2>
      <Key>Telephone</Key>
      <Value>0123 456 7896</Value>
    </Variable2>
    <Variable3>
      <Key>Car</Key>
      <Value>Chrysler</Value>
    </Variable3>
  </Data>
</MySavedData>
```

By using an XML file there is no limitation of having to STICK to predefined field names or field types, the user may type a number or string according to his/her variable type, for example a Color may be string like 'RED' or HEX like 'FF0000'

This would be much simpler than dabbling into SQL and by asking for a file name when loading and saving you may save/load a particular one.